# Crop Image Rectangle with Small Circle on Corner and Grid in the Mid (Adorner Concept) Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, crop

I am developing a Photo App in Windows Phone 7, I want, When I click on the Crop Button, the rectangle should be displayed with Small circles on Corner and Grid in the Mid, When I press the circle, it should be resize the rectangle and when I tap&hold the rectangle from Mid, it should be moved arround. As shown in the figure.

[image: Crop Area]

How it be possible. I checked the Adorner concept, but is it work in the Windows Phone?
Plz complete code if provided will much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit complex
refer this link for using resizing 
http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/custom-image-cropping-windows-0
and for dragging put whole assembly in a canvas and then apply MouseDragElementBehaviour on the cropping rectangle.
Sorry I couldnt provide you with the complete code fitting into your requirements, but you shall take a start with this.

Comment: This is actually, I got the same app phenomenon from the given link and also implemented, but this doesn't solve my problem. Plz give some more example, or check that app on ur PC and then let me know!

Comment: see, I can not give you the comolete code, but you would have to play a lot with the manipulation events, You take two rectangles one inside the othere and apply resize manipulation on the outer one and drag behaviour on the othere. this would seriously help you out

Comment: This idea gives a little bit help, but I need a clear idea having some proof, I mean some sample app or source code, to see the effect. Anyway, I will try and then will tell u. thanx.